# How to groupby a multiindex dataframe with different rules on different levels?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

If I have a dataframe like

```
In [58]: arrays = [
   ....:     ["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
   ....:     ["one1", "one2", "one1", "one2", "one1", "two", "one1", "two"],
   ....: ]
   ....: 

In [59]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=["first", "second"])

In [60]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], "B": np.arange(8)}, index=index)

In [61]: df
Out[61]: 
              A  B
first second      
bar   one1     1  0
      one2     1  1
baz   one1     1  2
      one2     1  3
foo   one1     2  4
      two     2  5
qux   one1     3  6
      two     3  7
```

Then I want a result

```
Out[61]: 
Out[61]: 
              A  B
first second      
bar   one     2  1
baz   one     2  5
foo   one     2  4
      two     2  5
qux   one     3  6
      two     3  7
```

That's to say, when 'level=0', I want to group by and remain its own index, at the same time , when 'level=1', I want to group by like `lambda x: x.startwith(x[:3])` and the new index into `x[:3]`.
So could it be achieved only with statement of `groupby`?Or some other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['second']= df['second'].str[:3]
df2 = df.groupby(['first', 'second'])[['A', 'B']].sum()
print(df2)
```

which gives:

```
              A  B
first second      
bar   one     2  1
baz   one     2  5
foo   one     2  4
      two     2  5
qux   one     3  6
      two     3  7
```